# laravel iteration adding amount on parent

Tags: php, laravel, loops, iteration

I mean, I have a referral system which is every `parent_id` has `parent` and the `parent_id` of that `parent` until it gets to the last `parent` which is the `Senior`.

Given that a user has purchased an item and it is successful, now I am calling the `insertEarnings` function to insert the corresponding amount to his `parent_id`, if his `parent_id` is `Junior` his `parent_id` will get `100`.

This is how the question begin, what if his `parent` doesn't have a `rank` meaning not `active`, the `amount`  to be insert to his `parent_id` will go through the next rank which is the `Premium` so the `Premium` will no have `250` total, after that proceed the normal insertion of the amount to the `parent_id` of Premium which is the `Advanced`- he will get the corresponding `amount` which is `200`, because the `rank` below him which is the `Premium` is existing, the insertion will go through until it gets to the last rank which is the `Senior`

Imagine that it is looping through the parent until it gets to the last rank - Senior.

The ranks are in order

```
Junior
Premium
Advanced
Senior
```

Ranks with their corresponding amount value

```
Junior - 100
Premium - 150
Advanced - 200
Senior - 250
```

Users table

```
+------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  id  |  username  |  parent_id  |   rank     |
+------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  1   |   john     |    NULL     |  Senior    |
|  2   |   jane     |    1        |  Advanced  |
|  3   |   josh     |    2        |  Premium   |
|  4   |   joey     |    3        |  Junior    |
|  5   |   jade     |    4        |  Basic     |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Code

```
$user_id = 5; // jade
$parent_id = 4;
    
// call the function to insert the earnings

self::insertEarnings($user_id,$parent_id);


private function insertEarnings($user_id,$parent_id) {
 
    if ($parent_id > 0) {
        
        $user_parent = $parent_id;
        
        $has_parent = true;
        
        // start iteration
        while($has_parent == true){
            
            $account = User::where('id',$user_parent)->first();
            
            $amount = 0;

            if ($account->rank == "Junior" ) {
                
                $amount = 100;
                    
            } elseif ($account->rank == "Premium") {

                $amount = 150;
                // for example this user/parent does not exist the amount(150) for him will be added to the next rank which is the Advance

            } elseif ($account->rank == "Advanced") {

                $amount = 200;
                
            } elseif ($account->rank == "Senior") {

                $amount = 250;
                
                // set to false to stop the iteration
                $has_parent = false;
            }

            $earnings = new Earnings;
            $earnings->user_id = $account->id;
            $earnings->amount = $amount;
            $earnings->save();
                    
            $next_parent = User::where('id',$user_parent)->first();
            $user_parent = $next_parent->parent_id;

            if($user_parent == 0){
                $has_parent = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `$user_id` is not used in this example, but there's a use to that that didn't included in the question because that is not the main problem.

Comment: What is your concrete problem? What doesn't it do that it should?

Comment: what do you mean @mrhn

Comment: I read the question multiple times and it does not state what it is not working? you are just explaining your problem? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: If you read it correctly you will understand.

This is how the question begin, what if his parent doesn't have a rank meaning not active, the amount  to be insert to his parent_id will go through the next rank which is the Premium so the Premium will no have 250 total, after that proceed the normal insertion of the amount to the parent_id of Premium which is the Advanced- he will get the corresponding amount which is 200, because the rank below him which is the Premium is existing, the insertion will go through until it gets to the last rank which is the Senior

Comment: Super, but stackoverflow is not about solving your problem, it is about fixing some code that does not work and i repeat what is not working?

Comment: No one has answered your fairly straight forward problem, don't you think that something is not formulated correctly? there are rules how to ask questions, i still dont know what does not work and tbh. im here for helping people have done it a lot, but you need to know what to fix.

Comment: ok, if you can understand you can edit my question to format it correctly

Comment: You have the almost exact same question posted where people state the same :) good luck